# Acknowledgement Timed out in quickblox chat...When trying to send image

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code
//Send message with attachment
self.dialogForChat.send(message){ (err) in
if err == nil{
self.txtMessage.text = ""
self.fetchMessages()
}else{
self.showAlert(message: err?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong", strtitle: "")

```
            }
        }
    }else{

    }
}else{
    self.dialogForChat.join { (err) in
        if err != nil{
            self.showAlert(message: err?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong", strtitle: "")
        }else{
            if QBChat.instance.isConnected == true {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dialogForChat.send(message){ (err) in
                        if err == nil{
                            self.txtMessage.text = ""
                            self.fetchMessages()
                        }else{
                            self.showAlert(message: err?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong", strtitle: "")

                        }
                    }
                }

            }else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't put the question inside the title, reformat the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @iOS testing did you find the solution for this, I need to impl the same scenario.

Comment: @iOS testing I update your question with details I am facing, but my scenario is to send any message and got that error Acknowledgement time out.

Comment: @Alastar I reformat the code and add the additional details in it. Kindly help us out, if you got our problem.